# Can't upload video file ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, mp4

I have an application where I need to upload video files. Just using Visual Studio 2013 on my local system. For some reason I can upload images and text files ok, but I can't upload mp4 or other video files. Here is my form header:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePerson", "Admin", FormMethod.Post,
    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

Here is my field:

```
<input type="file" name="File" id="File" />
```

Here is my Controller code.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePerson(SingleFileUpload theFileUpload, People p)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //UPLOAD FILE FIRST
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(theFileUpload.File.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/People/"), filename);
        theFileUpload.File.SaveAs(path);

        using (var db = new IFEntities())
        {
            p.Image = filename;
            p.OrderNumber = 0;

            var post = People.GetPerson(p);
            db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("ListPeople", new { id = p.Id });
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

However, when I submit, it doesn't hit the controller and I get an error.

The error is the generic:

> Runtime Error Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on the local server machine, please create a 
>   tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root
>   directory of the current web application. This  tag
>   should then have its "mode" attribute set to "RemoteOnly". To enable
>   the details to be viewable on remote machines, please set "mode" to
>   "Off".

Comment: As it is local, set `<customErrors mode="Off" />` in your web.config file. Then you can see the actual error, rather than the generic one.

Comment: Try setting bigger value for allowed upload size in `web.config` - http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm